# ubuntu 16.04, How to downgrade Perl from version 22 to version 20

Tags: 16.04, perl

I have perl  V5.22.1 installed by default in ubuntu 16.04 , I would like to know how to downgrade perl to version 5.20.3 , I have used perlbrew but it doesn't seem to work properly , are there any alternatives to perlbrew to downgrade perl , please let me know .

Comment: I'm using perlbrew without problems in ubuntu 16.04. Thus I recommend you figure out why perlbrew doesn't work properly because the chance is high that you are running in exactly the same problems with another way of installing an alternative version of perl.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  now i can use perlbrew, i have another problem, i would like to set Perl  5.20.3 as default perl instead of perl 5.22.3 . Could you please let me know how i can do that without perl brew, i know we can switch from one version of perl to another .

Comment: Please don't ask a different question in the comment of another question. Apart from that just read the documentation of perlbrew (`man perlbrew`) which includes the answer.

Answer (score 4):

List what you can install and use, with

```
perlbrew available
```

Install what you want from the list, with

```
perlbrew install perl-5.20.3
```

See what you can use in this system, with

```
perlbrew list
```

Use what you want, in the current shell with

```
 perlbrew use perl-5.20.2 # for this terminal only
 perlbrew switch perl-5.20.2 # every time you log-in
```

Revert to the older version with

```
perlbrew off        # for this terminal only
perlbrew switch-off # every time you log-in
```